# SignInManager.SignInAsync(.....) does not sign me in in ASP.NET Core Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I am learning ASP.Net Core Blazor and `SignInManager.SignInAsync` as well as `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` do not sign me in. I have tried several times but failed all the time. I can see that the data is there in the SQLServer database tables. I cannot see the password but user account is there. I have spent several days but could not figure it out

Here is my code

**Login Page component**

```
@page "/loginPage"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

@using GroupMembersInfo.Data;

@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h3>Log In</h3>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <EditForm Model="@LoginUserModel" OnValidSubmit="@LogIn">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <ValidationSummary />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>User Id: </label>
                <input @bind-value="LoginUserModel.Email" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password: </label>
                <input @bind-value="LoginUserModel.Password" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    public LoginUserModel LoginUserModel { get; set; } = new LoginUserModel();

    public async Task LogIn()
    {
        var user = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = LoginUserModel.Email,
            Email = LoginUserModel.Email
        };

        user.PasswordHash = SignInManager.UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, LoginUserModel.Password);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = new AuthenticationProperties();
        properties.IsPersistent = true;

        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, properties).ContinueWith(p =>
        {
            var User = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        });

        //var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, LoginUserModel.Password, isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: false);

        //if (result.Succeeded)
        //{
        //    var User = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
        //    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        //}
    }
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using GroupMembersInfo.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server;

namespace GroupMembersInfo
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("GMIDbConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 2;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;

                options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = cxt =>
                {
                    cxt.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

                options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = cxt =>
                {
                    cxt.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

                options.Events.OnRedirectToLogout = cxt => Task.CompletedTask;
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick guess would be to move `app.UseAuthentication();` and `app.UseAuthorization();` above `app.UseRouting();`

Comment: I tried that but it did not help.

Comment: Try changing the password complexity to `RequiredLength = 8`, `RequireDigit=true`, `RequireUppercase=true`, `RequireNonAlphanumeric=true`.  I know you shouldn't have to do this, but try it anyway.

Comment: this one also did not help.

Comment: I’d be surprised if a _server-side Blazor_ component could sign the user in through `SignInAsync`. This will set the cookie on the response but server-side Blazor usually runs outside of a request scope. So there is no HTTP response to be written. If you want to sign the user in, you will likely need a separate HTTP request to the server which then sets the cookie; and then you can restart the Blazor component to retrieve the updated result.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't sign in? result.Succeeded == false?

Comment: Yes result.Succeeded = false

Comment: I do not know how to make a separate HTTP request.

Comment: Same problem for me.  Sign-in is successful, cookie is set in the response, but there is No identity bound to subsequent requests (My RedirectToLogin component continuously believes it has no Authenticated Identity),  What do you mean restart the Blazor component @poke ?

Comment: @pseabury Have the browser navigate to the site again to re-establish a server connection.

Comment: @poke how would one accomplish that?  In my RedirectComponent I check AuthenticationStateProvider.(blah).IsAuthenticated and then NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/", true) to force the page to be loaded from the server, but AuthStateProvider never thinks I'm authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply sign in user with given email and password?

```
public async Task LogIn()
{
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(LoginUserModel.Email, LoginUserModel.Password, isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: false);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example I see commented code where you pass `new User()` instead of username. Did you noticed that? And what is in the output logs?

Comment: Did you try this (Login Component part) - https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/

Comment: Not yet but going to try it this week. I just went through whole page. Thank you very much for putting it all together. It is fantastic post.